# Need pithy translation for "I fall, yet I rise again"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Because our San Francisco Presidio hiking group is nearing its 20th anniversary, many of us have taken falls. I want a create a sew-on patch, in Latin, for those who have fallen but are still going strong. I only have choir Latin, but I know enough to see that Google Translate is wrong. I'd like a pithy translation of:

> I FALL, YET I RISE AGAIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose *Cado, sed resurgo*, meaning "I fall, but I rise again". *Cado* is good in the sense that is very short. *Resurgo* is literally "rise again", so there might not be something more direct and shorter than that.

Alternatives might come from changing *cado*, more in the context of "falling down" or "falling off". For instance, [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=praecipito) state that *praecipito* is appropriate for involuntary falling down. This word is also related to the English [precipice](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/precipice), which is surely used in hiking circles.

Another option is *[decido](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decido#Latin)*, also with the meaning of "falling off/down". This however is related to the English [decide](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decide#English), and so might lead to some confusion for non-Latin speakers.

So, perhaps the one with the clearest meaning, even for those without knowledge of Latin is *praecipito, sed resurgo*.